# Rust - How to specify a mutable lifetime and an immutable lifetime on the same parameter?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a function `foo` which has two mutable references as parameter: `vec1` and `vec2`. `foo` adds values to `vec1` and then stores references to these values in `vec2`. Hence, the lifetime of `vec1` is intermingled with the lifetime of the references in vec2. This results in the function definition `fn foo<'a>(vec1:&'a mut Vec<bool>, vec2:&mut Vec<&'a bool>)`. However, this means that `vec1` is now mutable as long as `vec2` lives. But `vec1` cannot be mutable after the call to foo. Is there a way to specify this?

A minimal reproducable example may look like this:

```
fn foo<'a>(vec1:&'a mut Vec<bool>, vec2:&mut Vec<&'a bool>){
    vec1.push(true);
    vec2.push(&vec1.get(0).unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = vec![];
    let mut vec2 = vec![];
    foo(&mut vec1, &mut vec2);
    bar(&vec1,&vec2);
}

fn bar(vec1:&Vec<bool>,vec2:&Vec<&bool>){

}
```

This results in the following compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec1` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
11 |     foo(&mut vec1, &mut vec2);
   |         --------- mutable borrow occurs here
12 |     bar(&vec1,&vec2);
   |         ^^^^^ ----- mutable borrow later used here
   |         |
   |         immutable borrow occurs here
```

Defining `foo` so that `vec1` is mutable in the scope of `foo` but lives as immutable reference for lifetime `'a` would solve my problem and not hurt Rust's borrow rules.

I guess this is not possible and I need some workaround with `RefCell`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding lifetimes, I don't think you can avoid this lifetime extension beyond the function call. What you can do, is decouple those mutable references to the vectors. For example, you can split the function in parts like so

```
fn foo_start(vec:&mut Vec<bool>) {
    vec.push(true);
}

fn foo_end<'a>(src: &'a Vec<bool>, idx: usize, dest:&mut Vec<&'a bool>) {
    dest.push(src.get(idx).unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = vec![];
    let mut vec2 = vec![];
    
    foo_start(&mut vec1);
    foo_end(&vec1, 0, &mut vec2);
    bar(&vec1,&vec2);
}

fn bar(vec1:&Vec<bool>,vec2:&Vec<&bool>){

}
```

Unfortunately it may break some "encapsulation" of your algorithm, as you'll need to link the data flow between those two splitted functions

Comment: Thank you very much. I was already considering this.